# How to log state on minitest failure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, minitest

Say I have a test

```
describe "import stuff"
  it "should import correctly"
     imported_count = import_stuff()
     assert_equal 3, imported_count
  end
end
```

How do I log the database state e.g. `puts ImportedStuff.all.to_json` when the test fails?

I know I can specify the error message like this `assert_equals 3, imported_count, 'my message'`. But I don't want to invoke ImportedStuff.all.to_json when the tests succeed. `assert_equals` seems to only accept a string for the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it doesn't appear to be documented you can pass a `Proc` as a message. The proc passed will be invoked only on failure.

Example:

```
def print_db_state
  Proc.new { puts DimensionType.all.to_json }
end

describe "import stuff"
  it "should import correctly"
     imported_count = import_stuff()
     assert_equal 3, imported_count, print_db_state
  end
end
```

Passing `ImportedStuff.all.to_json` will invoke `all.to_json` every time the assertion is executed even if the test doesn't fail - not good.

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't need to log the database status for a test. Tests help you determine if everything is ok, or if there's something that needs your attention. If the test fails, then you can always re-run it adding a log for the database.

If you want the log to be there, I'd say to add an if:

```
imported_count = import_stuff()
if imported_count==3
 puts ImportedStuff.all.to_json
end
assert_equal 3, imported_count
```

Another option you have, is to put the logging in an `after` block.

EDIT

If you want to log your errors if your test fails, you can add:

```
def teardown
  unless passed?
    puts ImportedStuff.all.to_json
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm writing the tests as I develop and they fail a lot because I do the tests before the code -- so having info about what caused the failure is important.. To rephrase my question: is there something in minitest that would help me to log stuff elegantly on failure? Or do I have to hack it with if's etc.?

Comment: I added an example of using `teardown`, which I think is similar to what you want

Answer (score 0):

Minitest prints passed message only if assertion had failed ( https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest/assertions.rb#L127 ). You can pass "ImportedStuff.all.to_json" and don't afraid that it would be calculated for successful assertion.

You could also pass a parameterless Proc to all minitest assertions as message ( instead of String ), it would be called when test fails and it's result would be printed as message.